# ¿Cómo puedo hacer este select con Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Esta es mi consulta con  SQL

```
Select * from  HotCategorias    
Where HotCategoriasId in(
SELECT  HTAR_CategoriaId      
  FROM HotTarifas
  Where HTAR_HotelID = 2 and HTAR_AcomodacionId = 3)
```

Esta es mi consulta con Linq, El problema es en el resultado no me sale igual con SQL

```
var HotCat = from HoCa in contexto.HotCategoria
   from HT1 in contexto.HotTarifas                                
      from HT2 in (
           (from HotTarifa in contexto.HotCategoria
                select new
                 {
                  CategoriasId = HotTarifa.HotCategoriasId,
                  CAT_Nombre = HotTarifa.CAT_Cat1,
                }))
             where HT1.HTAR_CategoriaId == 2 &&  
               HT1.HTAR_HotelID == 3
            select new Item
             {
            id= HT2.CategoriasId,
            value = HT2.CAT_Nombre,
          };
return HotCat.ToList();
```

Comment: Si intenté pero no me sale el resultado como debe ser. Le agrego mi consulta de Linq a mi pregunta.

Comment: ok. podes agregar tambien el resultado obtenido y el resultado esperado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no he entendido mal la consulta puedes simplificarla bastante. Vendría a ser algo así:

```
var HotCat = from HoCa in contexto.HotCategoria
        where contexto.HotTarifas.Any(
            t => t.HTAR_HotelID == 2 && t.HTAR_AcomodacionId == 3 && t.HTAR_CategoriaId == HoCa.HotCategoriasId)
        select new Item { id = HoCa.HotCategoriasId, value = HoCa.CAT_Nombre };
```

Comment: Genial, #Asier Villanueva  me servio mucho muchas gracias

Comment: Gran respuesta, enhorabuena